Is this Android Camera concept feasible?
I'm curious whether this concept is feasible on a chipset that supports Android 13.

Is it possible for the four camera apps, a, b, c, and d, to operate simultaneously?
If the camera throughput or chipset performance is insufficient, would it be possible to operate in three cases: A / B and C / D?
